The matrix equation of the form $AX+XA^{-T}=0$ has a nonsingular anti-symmetric solution $X$
I want to prove that for $A=J_n(i)$, that is, the Jordan block matrix corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$ of size $n$, where $n$ is even, the matrix equation $AX+XA^{-T}=0$ has a nonsingular anti-symmetric solution $X$.
I have tried it on small values of $n$ (= 2,4,6) by brute force computations and proved that it is true.
Any ideas on how can I prove this for an arbitrary even $n$? Ideas or suggestions would suffice. Thank you so much!

What does $A^{-T}$ mean?

@WimC  $A^{-T}= (A^T)^{-1}= (A^{-1})^T$

Observe that $A^T = PAP$, where $P$ is the unit antidiagonal matrix (and so $P = P^{-1} = P^T$) and that
$A$ is similar to $-A^{-1}$ via a matrix $U$, so $A = U(-A^{-1})U^{-1}$.
By taking the inverses of these two equalities, we also get $A^{-T} = PA^{-1}P$ and $A^{-1} = U(-A)U^{-1}$.
Now define $X_1=UP$, $X_2 = (UP)^T$. Your equation is linear, so if we show $X_1$, $X_2$ are solutions, then so is any linear combination of the two.
We can write the initial equation as
$$
\begin{align}
AX + XA^{-T} &= AX+X(PAP)^{-1} \\
&= AX - XP(-A^{-1})P \\
&= AX - XP(U^{-1}AU)P = AX- XPU^{-1}AUP
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in the value of $X_1$ gives:
$AX_1 + X_1A^{-T} = AUP - (UPPU^{-1})AUP = AUP - AUP = 0$, so $X_1$ is a (nonsingular) solution.
Similarly, we can write the transpose of the initial equation as
$$\begin{align}
(AX + XA^{-T})^T &= A^{-1}X^T+X^T(A^T) \\ 
&= A^{-1}X^T+X^T(A^{-1})^{-T} \\
&= U(-A)U^{-1}X^T+X^T(PA^{-1}P)^{-1} = -UAU^{-1}X^T+X^TPAP
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $X_2 = (UP)^T$ gives:
$(AX_2 + X_2A^{-T})^T = -UA(U^{-1}U)P + U(PP)AP = -UAP + UAP = 0$, so $AX_2 + X_2A^{-T} = 0^T = 0$, and therefore $X_2$ is also a (nonsingular) solution.
To find the antisymmetric solution we simply take $$\boxed{X = X_1 - X_2 = UP - (UP)^T}$$
This is a linear combination of $X_1, X_2$ so it is a solution, is antisymmetric, as it is equal to $2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(UP - (UP)^T)$ (so twice the antisymmetric part of $UP$). The matrix $X$ is also (almost certainly) nonsingular, but I do not have a nice proof of this fact.
